# Converting Javascript code

Tags: javascript, parsing, tokenize

This is a very basic question. I tried searching SO, but couldn't get any solid answer. Sorry if it's really basic.

I'm trying to write a plugin/library to convert Javascript into [Apache Jelly](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/).

So the idea is to write Javascript code, which will be converted to Jelly code.

example: Javascript like code:

```
if(x == 1){
  print("inside if");
}
```

Apache converted code:

```
  <j:if test="x=1">
     inside if
  </j:if>
```

The question is, how do I parse the entire Javascript code and replace it with some other code. I did have a look at Jison but that basically is a parse generator, which parses the values AND interpret them. I feel using jison is kinda overhead for my task.

Any idea what I can use to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Edit 1: Yes, there is a Javascript top down parser at [JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js), but any easy way to specify what needs to be replaced? for example, in the above code - replacing `if` loop with `<j:if>`

Comment: If you want to parse JavaScript with JavaScript, the [JSLint source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js) might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks, How do I replace what I just parsed?

Comment: A program that interprets JavaScript source code to discover the program structure it describes is called a **JavaScript parser**. That's what you have to write.

Comment: You generate the new code while parsing the original. JSLint aim is to validate JS code, you'll have read that code, understand it, and adapt it for your own needs. I don't think you can achieve what you're looking for without understanding how the a parser works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably misunderstood the Jison calculator example. You don't *have* to execute any code in the parser, it's just the calculator that does that to illustrate the concept. You can put any stuff you want in a parser action, for example, to generate your xml format the code might be like:

```
 `if` condition block:
      { $$ = '<j:if test=' + $2 + '>' + $3 + '</if>' }
```

Another (and better) option is to use a abstract JS parser to build an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and generate XML by walking this tree. That has an advantage of decoupling parsing from code generation + you can simply utilize an already made grammar like https://github.com/cjihrig/jsparser.

Comment: Just wanted to add, There is a beautiful parser from Mozilla called [Esprima](http://esprima.org/), better than the one given by thg435.